# repeat an iteration of for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

if for some reason i want to repeat the same iteration how i can do it in python?

```
for eachId in listOfIds:
    #assume here that eachId conatins 10
    response = makeRequest(eachId) #assume that makeRequest function request to a url by using this id
    if response == 'market is closed':
       time.sleep(24*60*60) #sleep for one day
```

now when the function wake up from sleep after one day (market (currency trade market) is open) i want to resume my for loop from `eachId = 10` `not` from `eachId = 11`, because `eachId = 10` is not yet been processed as `market was closed`, any help is highly appreciated thanks.

Comment: save the content into a list.

Comment: I think what he's asking is how to not increment the `for` loops list counter on one iteration.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
for eachId in listOfIds:
    successful = False
    while not successful:        
        response = makeRequest(eachId)
        if response == 'market is closed':
            time.sleep(24*60*60) #sleep for one day
        else:
            successful = True
```

The title of your question is the clue. *Repeating* is achieved by iteration, and in this case you can do it simply with a nested `while`.

Comment: thanks for help, nested while ahhh how this not came in to my mind :p

Answer (score 8):

Use a `while` loop?

```
counter = 0
while counter < len(listOfIds):
  # do processing
  counter = counter + 1
```

And just don't increment, if you get 'market is closed'.

Answer (score 2):

```
i = 0
while i < len(listOfIds):
    eachId = listOfIds[i]
    #assume here that eachId conatins 10
    response = makeRequest(eachId) #assume that makeRequest function request to a url by using this id
    if response == 'market is closed':
       time.sleep(24*60*60) #sleep for one day
    else:
       i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for eachId in listOfIds:
    while makeRequest(eachId) == 'market is closed':
       time.sleep(24*60*60) #sleep for one day
```

As @David added, if you don't need to capture `response`.

Comment: This is good unless the `response` needs to be captured. Otherwise this must be close to as concise as possible.