# Don't go to next iteration in for loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Not sure if this is possible, mostly a curiosity question although I may have a case where this may be useful. Basically I'm wondering if it's possible to not go to the next iteration in a loop, and instead try repeating that iteration. For example:

```
myList = ['a','b','c']

for thing in myList:

    if something:
        continue
    else:
        try again (same iteration)
```

Is what I'm asking for clear? A way I've seen of doing this is to use a while loop operating only on the first element of a list and then continuously deleting the first element of the list if some condition is met.

Thanks

Comment: see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293978/repeat-an-iteration-of-for-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop and manually substract from the iteration variable. Demo:

```
import time
myList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
i = 0
while i < len(myList):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(i)
    if i == 3:
        i -= 1
    i += 1
```

Of course, you'll need to access your `thing` by indexing into `myList` now, i.e. do something to/with `myList[i]`.

Comment: good idea, I didn't know that worked though

Comment: @Sam Creamer It does not work with for i in range(foo), but a while loop will do the trick.