# Python: Repeat current iteration after correction

Tags: python, for-loop

I am wrecking my brains out about this problem. I have a for-loop and within it, check for a condition. Something like this:

```
filename = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
headername = [1,2,3,4,5]
newfield = 6

for i in filename:
    print i, headername
    if newfield not in headername:
        headername.append(newfield)
```

The output is:

```
a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, I want the the current iteration to repeat itself when it fails the condition. So that the result is something like this. Can anyone help?

```
a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**
It is essential that I repeat the current loop (after condition is met after correction), not just adding an additional print statement. I apologise that I truncate my initial code, so let me further explain.

I have a list of files, and for each file I read them line by line, and compare them to an existing list, if it exists I will write the line into a new csv file. However, if I encounter any new unique lines I will need to, add that unique line to the existing list, delete the csv file and restart the current loop again.

The reason I did not scan all files for any unique lines first, is because I have a lot of files, and each file size is very large.

```
for i in files:
    outputFile = 'outputfile_{}.csv'.format(i)
    csvwriter= csv.writer(outputFile, delimiter=',')
    with open(i) as file:
        for line in file:
            field = line.split(',')[0]
            if field not in headername:
                os.remove(outputfile)
                headername.append(field )
            else:
                csvwriter.writerow(outputfile)
```

Comment: At this point I think adding a `print i, headername` in the `if` body would work.

Comment: What you want is probably more than simply spoofing yourself with printing stuffs. Are you trying to merge your files and then generating the union of their respective `headername` ? Where is `6` coming from ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [repeat an iteration of for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293978/repeat-an-iteration-of-for-loop)

Comment: @DrimadesBoy please see my edits

Comment: @SiHa its not a duplicate, I want it to rerun the loop one more time after the condition is met. That example will skip to the next loop once condition is met.

Comment: The idea in that post *will* work, if implemented correctly.

Comment: Would you be able to demonstrate an example if possible? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another less pythony way would be this:

```
filename = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
headername = [1,2,3,4,5]
newfield = 6
j = 0

while j < len(filename):
    i = filename[j]
    print i, headername
    if newfield not in headername:
        headername.append(newfield)
    else:
        j += 1
```

Also prints the desired result

Comment: seems to work, let me try to my full script and get back!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
filename = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
headername = [1,2,3,4,5]
newfield = 6

for i in filename:
    print i, headername
    if newfield not in headername:
        headername.append(newfield)
        print i, headername
```

output :

```
a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
c [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
d [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: thanks :) however, the main purpose is to reiterate the current loop based on condition. Sorry for my wording, I have added some edits to my post.