# Python: How to "redo" an iteration of a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have this piece of code (for practice):

```
def choose_dice():
    while True:
        try:
            dice_quantity = int(input("How many dice would you like to use? "))
            dice_sides = []
            for current_dice in range(1, dice_quantity + 1):
                sides = int(input("How many sides on {} dice? ".format(str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice))))
                dice_sides.append([str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice) + " dice", sides])
#               print(dice_sides)
            return dice_sides
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as _:
            print("Oops, it seems you have entered a non integer ")
```

Which prompts the user for a number and then for x in range(1, number) prompts the user to chose a number.

In the case of the user typing in a non integer or nothing whilst in the for loop, I want to return to the current iteration of the for loop instead of starting all over.

How can I elegantly achieve this?

i.e the current behavior is as such:

"How many dice would you like to use? 3

How many sides on 1st dice? 6

How many sides on 2nd dice? 0

How many sides on 3rd dice?

Oops, it seems you have entered a non integer

How many dice would you like to use? "

If a user doesn't enter anything, it gets caught in the exception and the whole process starts over. I want it to retry the current "How many sides on n'th dice?" instead of starting the loop from scratch

Comment: When a user enters 0, what behavior do you want to happen? Could you please clarify?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [repeat an iteration of for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7293978/repeat-an-iteration-of-for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
def choose_dice():
    while True:
        try:
            dice_quantity = int(input("How many dice would you like to use? "))
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as _:
            print("Oops, it seems you have entered a non integer ")

        dice_sides = []
        current_dice = 1
        while current_dice != dice_quantity + 1:
            try:
                sides = int(input("How many sides on {} dice? ".format(str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice))))
                dice_sides.append([str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice) + " dice", sides])
                current_dice += 1
            except (TypeError, ValueError, NameError) as _:
                print("Oops, it seems you have entered a non integer ")
        print(dice_sides)
        return dice_sides
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
sides = int(input("How many sides on {} dice? ".format(str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice))))
```

with this function:

```
getSidesOnDice()
```

and here is the defintion of getSidesOnDice:

```
def getSidesOnDice():
    while True: 
        try:
            sides = int(input("How many sides on {} dice? ".format(str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice))))
            break
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as _: 
            print("Oops, it seems you have entered a non integer ")
    return sides
```

so your code would look like this:

```
def getSidesOnDice(current_dice):
    while True: 
        try:
            sides = int(input("How many sides on {} dice? ".format(str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice))))
            break
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as _: 
            print("Oops, it seems you have entered a non integer ")
    return sides

def choose_dice():
    while True:
        try:
            dice_quantity = int(input("How many dice would you like to use? "))
            dice_sides = []
            for current_dice in range(1, dice_quantity + 1):
                sides = getSidesOnDice(current_dice)
                dice_sides.append([str(current_dice) + ordinal(current_dice) + " dice", sides])
            print(dice_sides)
            return dice_sides
        except (TypeError, ValueError) as _:
            print("Oops, it seems you have entered a non integer ")
```

You may also inline the function in your code. The simple explanation is that you don't want the line which gets the sides for the current_dice to go further if it didn't get a valid value. So the simplest way is to replace it with a function and then work on the function to make it do what you expect. Then if you felt you want the function to be inlined in the main code, put it there and get rid of the function. Thinking of a function even in your mind will break down the tasks to smaller pieces that are more easily achievable.